# Requesting different websites with IP and headers

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, iis, hacking

Is it possible to lure a website from the web server without relying on DNS records?
Windows IIS WebServer was working with headers, Linux is working with virtual server names etc.

Imagine this situation:

- Server (linux + apache) directly accessible from the internet with his own IP (123.45.67.89).
  With default page like: "It's working!"
- In Apache(httpd) a Virtual server is set like: server name: www.site.net , listening to any address default port.
- I don't have DNS record saying like: www.stie.net - M -> 123.45.67.89
- I don't have my own DNS server set up and dont want to route sites on different ports.

**How can I access stored websites with only IP address and known hosted site name?**

Answer (score 0):

Edit your local hosts file.

In Linux it's on:

```
/etc/hosts
```

For windows it should be

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\
```

Check that [reference wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) page to find yours.

This will act as a local-only DNS for your development workstation, add # before the lines when you want to comment a line (when DNS will be active).

**Edit:** You can of course have several names for the same IP, this way:

```
192.168.0.1 foo.bar.com foobar.nenet.com
```

or this way:

```
192.168.0.1 foo.bar.com 
192.168.0.1 foobar.nenet.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) program, which could be used as an effective local DNS cache.

> Dnsmasq is a lightweight, easy to
>   configure DNS forwarder and DHCP
>   server.
>
> ...
>
> Dnsmasq provides the following features:
>
> - The DNS configuration of machines behind the firewall is simple and doesn't depend on the details of the ISP's dns servers
>
> ...

You can find a nice tutorial on how-to use dnsmasq as local DNS cache [here](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/08/02/local-dns-cache-for-faster-browsing/).

Answer (score 0):

I would advice against changing your /etc/hosts or setting up local DNS servers.
You will run into caching issues, forget to disable it, etc.
Use curl:

> curl -H"Host:www.site.net" http://123.45.67.89

Or if you want to see the content rendered, use a Firefox Plugin (http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/).
Livehttpheaders allows you to change any header and "replay" them.
Change the Host header and it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to type IP address in browser and access web server that runs there (e.g. `http://123.123.123.123/`).

If so -- Yes, you can do it but, obviously, it will be one site per IP:port combination.

I cannot really tell you how this can be done on Apache (don't have much experience configuring it) but for **Microsoft IIS 7.x** it can be done in this way:

1) Select the site entry and bring "Site Bindings" dialogue.

2) Type, IP address & port number -- select desired settings; Host name -- **leave blank**

3) Save settings and try the results. If does not work then you must be done something wrong (or such binding already exists).

Microsoft IIS 6 can be configured in a similar way -- just different path/buttons to press.